# How do i drill into a json array with axios

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I have an axios call like:

```
   axios.get('api')
   .then(response => {
   console.log('response', response);
   })
```

And this works fine to return the api call. But it returns as such:

```
    result{
    data[{
        data2:[{
        inner array's object data
        }]}
    ]}
```

I need to know how to get into the data of the inner array's object with aboves console.log....

Comment: That second snippet is not a proper object. I would guess `response.data[0].data2` would get you the inner array.

Comment: this works, but in the format response.data[0].data2[0]. Now how could i map over that via state? I want to cycle through the second array's objects.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far and what you want to accomplish in your question. It's not a good idea to change your question after it has been answered.

Comment: The above only returns the first object in data, and the first object in data 2. I want to store all of the objects in data2 in state. Basically im drilling down into a json array twice. Data2 in each of data's objects only contains 1 object in its array.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drill in with `response.data[0].data2` for example.

Comment: this returns undefined for me.